# .net core how to register ihubcontext in the autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, autofac

I have to register ihubcontext in the autofac.My team intergation test use auto to auto resolve like below.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestGetReadyRoundCode()
{
    var expected = true;
    var target = AutofacConfig.GetContainer(new ServiceCollection(), Config.ConnectionStrings, Config.MongoDBConnectionStrings).Resolve<ILotteryRoundService>();
    var result = await target.GetReadyRoundCode(LotteryNameKey.chongqingSSC.ToInt());
    Console.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented));
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result.Success);
}
```

I tried  way to register signalr.But get throw execption.

```cs
builder
      .RegisterGeneric(typeof(IHubContext<,>))
      .As(typeof(IHubContext<,>))
      .AsImplementedInterfaces()
      .SingleInstance()
      .PropertiesAutowired();
```

I also followed [this link](https://recalll.co/ask/v/topic/asp.net-mvc-Autofac-injection-of-IHubContext-SignalR-MVC/5a1395941126f4051d8b6fe1). But I can't build success.

Can anyone help me this problem?